# How to import/export java-script files on Browser?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I have 2 files (in the same folder), let's say myFile.js and anotherFile.js, I created a Chrome extension and it works perfect! However, I have my whole code in one file (.js). I want to separate the code into two separate files, but I don't know how to import one to the other! I have tried these ways so far: (I added this code to myFile.js)

```
     import * from './anotherFile.js';
```

It keeps giving me-> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

AND I also tried this:

```
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.setAttribute('type', 'module');
     script.innerHTML = 'import * from \'./anotherFile.js\'';
```

and I included "export" in the anotherFile.js, but both ways didn't work!
Any suggestions??? (remark: I'm using PURE javascript. I'm applying the code in Chrome browser)

Comment: Importing `something` requires that `something` to be exported. Importing everything `*` requires each thing you want available to be exported (a named export). What did you export from  `anotherFile.js`?

Comment: I think you should try using the `require` statement as `import` requires transpilation and I am not sure you have that available here.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I put only 1 function in anotherFile.js (just for test) and I exported it, but it didn't work. It seems there is a special command for browsers!

Comment: @Michael require doesn't work with browsers (I tried it also).

Comment: Assuming the first file is included in the HTML file with a `<script>` tag, then in order for this to work, the type attribute of the `<script>` tag must be set to `type/module`: `<script type="module" src="myFile.js"></script>`

Comment: @Michael - you are fully incorrect.

Comment: @Michael that's what I found here http://browserify.org/ when I was looking for a solution

Comment: @hassan feel free to upvote my comment :-)